# Intellij Idea maven repositories remote error

Tags: maven, repository, intellij-idea

I have problem with Intellij Idea 10.5 on my Mac OS X 10.6.7. When I try to get some dependencies trough "Maven Artifact search", I have always blank area. So I check the intellij maven repositories settings and there are red marked line with repository "repo1.maven.org/maven2". When I try open this page, it gave me an redirect choice to "http://search.maven.org/#browse" page. So my question is, it is possible to change somewhere in intellij the indexed maven repository url? If yes, than where?

Answer (score 2):

From top menu, open File -> Settings -> Maven -> Repositories and verify that you have valid remote repository.

[image: Settings Window]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure where IDEA will look for Maven repo by editing your settings.xml file (see [Maven Projects Tool Window](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven-projects-tool-window.html)).

That being said, I don't think that the Maven public repo address being not browsable is an issue (even though there is a [recent pending question on that topic](http://forums.atlassian.com/message.jspa?messageID=257376671#257376671))